# How to hide an element based on another existing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery code that looks for a specific `div` element.

If the element exist I define a variable and use `parseFloat()` function. Since there are going to be more than one element with the same class I've created an array.

So far I've managed to hide the element called: `div.ifc-balance-div`; however I am not quite sure **how** I can hide the `div.ribbon-yellow`, in case the element does not have the variable `savePrice`.

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var j = 0,
        savePrices = jQuery('.special-price .price .price').map(function() {
            return parseFloat(jQuery(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
        }).get();

    if(j < savePrices.length){
        ++j;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < savePrices.length; ++i) {
      if (Number(savePrices[i]) > 0) {
        var ifcBalance = Number(savePrices[i]) / 1,
            m = parseFloat(ifcBalance).toFixed(0);

        $('div.ifc-balance-div' + (i + 1)).html('<p class="dynamic-badge-txt"><b>£' + m + ' OFF</b></p>');
        $('div.ribbon-yellow').html('<div class="badge-ends-message">ENDS TUESDAY</div>');
      } 
      else {
        $('div.ifc-balance-div' + (i + 1)).hide();
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a sample of the HTML Code:

1. one having Save Price:

   Text

   ```
       <div class="price-box">
           <p class="old-price">
           <span class="price-label">Was</span>
           <span class="price" id="old-price-15510">
                               <span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>599</span>            </span>
       </p>

       <p class="special-price">
           <span class="price-label">You Save</span>
           <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-15510">
               <span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>300</span>            </span>
       </p>
   </div>
   ```

   From 
           £299
2. One without save price:

   ```
   <div class="ribbon-yellow"></div>
   <div>
   </div></div></div>
           <a href="#" title="#">
               <img src="#" alt="#">
           </a>
       </div>
       <div class="item__detail">
           <a href="#" title="#" class="item__link">
               <p class="product-name item__name">Text</p>
           </a>

   <div class="price-range">
               <span class="price-label">From </span>
           <span class="price"><span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>299</span></span>
   </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, hide an element or add a div ? Also why can't you just write a conditional for the `savePrince` var ?

Comment: @Pogrindis Currently I can hide this element: "div.ifc-balance-div" My question is how can I hide the other two if the savePrice doesn't exist : "div.ribbon-yellow", "div.ribbon"

Comment: `if(!savePrince){ $("div.ribbon-yellow").hide(); }` - The same way you've done the rest..

Comment: I have more than one product with the same classes: "ifc-balance-div", "ribbon-yellow", "ribbon" Some of them they have "var savePrices" some of them don't. That is why I've put it in array and apply only if it exist. Applying the above code doesn't hide the "ribbon-yellow", "ribbon" if they don't exist. The only field that is hidden is the one in the array "div.ifc-balance-div"

Comment: hide them all, then make the ones that are appropriately associated visible

Comment: show us the HTML structure

Comment: @Andi I've just updated my question

Comment: @John just to be perfectly clear: you need to hide certain `div` elements based off `savePrice[i]` existing at each for loop iteration right? If that is true, are `ifc-balance-div`, `ribbon-yellow` and `ribbon` the only classes you want to hide? Third comment, I noticed you use `(i + 1)` to hide each of the previous three classes instance per index, meaning you have many elements under the same class and you want to hide each by index... is this also true?

Comment: What's the common parent element between the items with .special-price and those without?  Please show your HTML in both cases starting from that common element.

Comment: @Age that is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: is the class name `ribben-yellow` or like: `ribben-yellow0`, `ribben-yellow1`, `ribben-yellow2` and so on?

Comment: The class is "ribbon-yellow" as it is static and will always contain the same text the other one is "ifc-balance-div1", "ifc-balance-div2" and etc